# .keyboard is not a function when used with React

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, keyboard

I want to get user input from a textarea using jquery keyboard.js.

The keyboard that I am using: https://github.com/Mottie/Keyboard

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

These are my imports in my file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
import keyboard from '../../../../node_modules/virtual-keyboard/dist/js/jquery.keyboard.js';
```

And this is my code:

```
export default class KEyboard extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
         ...
         jQuery(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.keyboard)).keyboard(this.props.options);
```

this.refs.keyboard is good. already debug it. Same as this.props.options

And this is my webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
const validate = require('webpack-validator');


var config = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
  path: __dirname,
  filename: 'bundle.js'
},
devtool: 'source-map',
eslint: {
  configFile: './.eslintrc'
},
module: {
  preLoaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'eslint-loader'
    },
  ],
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      query: {
        presets: ['es2015', 'react']
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    },
    /*
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
    },
   */
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: 'style-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: 'css-loader',
      query: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loader: 'sass-loader'
    },
    /*
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
    }
    */
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|png)$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[hash].[ext]'
    },
  ]
},
};
```

module.exports = validate(config);

Comment: Are you loading jQuery in any other way than `import`?

Comment: Not possible to answer without looking at your webpack config. It is possible that you're referencing a different instance of jQuery (window.jQuery) in componentDidMount instead of the locally (imported) scoped one. Try import jq from 'jQuery', use that, and see what happens. Even if that does work, you should never, ever run two instances of jQuery at any given time. You should inject it into global scope using webpack.ProvidePlugin, like so.

Comment: Thanks @natnai, I was loading Jquery in my html file, but after I remove it,  jquery UI started to give me problems. I tried changing the jQuery to jq and it didnt work either

Comment: Then what you need to do is use `ProvidePlugin`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ProvidePlugin`.

```
...

plugins: [ new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ jQuery: 'jquery', $: 'jquery' }) ]

...
```

Then in your component, simply refer to `jQuery` as if it were a global variable on the `window` object. You can do the same for jquery-ui. Do not `import` it. The fact that `jquery` is already on the global scope, and then re-imported in the module, and isn't behaving correctly in the module, would seem to suggest there is a conflict.

`ProvidePlugin` will cause all other modules that depend on `jQuery` to extend from a single global instance of `jQuery`. This should solve your problem. That should solve the jquery-ui problem and your current one as well. Make sure to remove it from your `html` template(s).

See [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your help, I already tried everything you've told me so far, and  it just doesn't work. I'll keep trying though

Answer (score 0):

So, at the end the problem was the version of the virtual keyboard.

I followed the following steps:

1. npm install --save virtual-keyboard@1.26.13
2. npm install
3. npm run build
4. npm run watch

Opened the project in incognito to make sure there is no cache problem, and it worked!